# Cascade deletion in WCF Data Services

Tags: silverlight, wcf, wcf-data-services, cascade, astoria

Is it possible to delete persistent objects graph by the single command using WCF Data Services in Silverlight?
I've started with [this walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681615%28VS.95%29.aspx) and added code for deletion of selected order (which contains details):

```
private void deleteOrder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Order deletedOrder = (Order)ordersGrid.SelectedItem;

    // Delete the selected order.
    svcContext.DeleteObject(deletedOrder);

    // Remove the deleted order from the binding collection.
    ordersGrid.SelectedIndex = ordersGrid.SelectedIndex == 0 ? 1 : ordersGrid.SelectedIndex - 1;
    ordersBindingCollection.Remove(deletedOrder);
}
```

When I save changes back to server, delete request is issued:

```
--batch_2009b119-0747-4019-8974-8ea7dd29963a
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_b451aecf-b66d-4f0f-8e6d-8a067646b350

--changeset_b451aecf-b66d-4f0f-8e6d-8a067646b350
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

DELETE http://localhost:55378/PurchasesService.svc/Orders(1) HTTP/1.1
Content-ID: 90

--changeset_b451aecf-b66d-4f0f-8e6d-8a067646b350--
--batch_2009b119-0747-4019-8974-8ea7dd29963a--
```

But it fails on the database end with the foreign key constraint violation:

```
--batchresponse_b6c22c24-17ec-409b-ba91-91784116927d
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changesetresponse_41e6e873-a5dd-446d-bda0-99405ba92a63

--changesetresponse_41e6e873-a5dd-446d-bda0-99405ba92a63
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-ID: 90
Cache-Control: no-cache
DataServiceVersion: 1.0;
Content-Type: application/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code></code>
  <message xml:lang="uk-UA">An error occurred while processing this request.</message>
</error>
--changesetresponse_41e6e873-a5dd-446d-bda0-99405ba92a63--
--batchresponse_b6c22c24-17ec-409b-ba91-91784116927d--
```

I've also tried to set relation's **OnDelete** property to **Cascade** in .edmx

Is it possible to make such deletions? Who should take care of deleting referenced objects: client or server? And how many delete requests should be sent to the server: one or N+1 (where N is number of details of given order). Maybe I'm missing some key point. Are there any WCF Data Services tutorials describing deletion of object graphs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YAY! I figured it! =D Ive been at the same thing for hours today!

> So I didn't set Cascade in the edmx.

**You set it in the database**

In SQL Server Management Studio:

1. In a *database diagram* select the relationship you want to cascade delete
2. Open properties
3. Expand *Insert And Update*
4. Set the Delete rule to Cascade.

Reload/Update your entity framework model. When you do this, visual studio will update the CSDL/SSDL (Whatever?).

[Reference from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738695.aspx):
 *"When you want to automatically delete all of the child records of a parent when the parent record is deleted you can specify the cascade delete rule. It is strongly recommended that you **specify the cascade** delete rules in both the conceptual model and the **database**."*